# Lumen request is empty on special characters in input JSON

Tags: php, swagger, lumen

I have a webservice in Lumen. I integrated Swagger for API DOCS.

Input Json

```
{"teamId" : 169, "teamName" : "lm", "teamDescription" : "lmnshhhdjj 
dhhduxuh 
dbbduxhehd 
dhhdh8xbbbdhe uudbdhue", "nationality" : "AU", "timezone" : "0"}
```

Here the key `teamDescription` is a string having new line characters in it. After submitting the request, `$request->all()` is empty. But for a plain string this problem is not there.

Comment: Newline characters are not valid in JSON. How did that invalid string get constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newline characters are not valid in JSON. How did that invalid string get constructed?

Take a look at this simple demonstration creating a *valid* JSON encoded string of your data:

```
<?php
$input = [
    "teamId" => 169,
    "teamName" => "lm",
    "teamDescription" => "lmnshhhdjj
dhhduxuh
dbbduxhehd
dhhdh8xbbbdhe uudbdhue",
    "nationality" => "AU",
    "timezone" => "0"
];
var_dump(json_encode($input));
```

The output is:

```
string(144) "{"teamId":169,"teamName":"lm","teamDescription":"lmnshhhdjj \ndhhduxuh \ndbbduxhehd \ndhhdh8xbbbdhe uudbdhue","nationality":"AU","timezone":"0"}"
```

Comment: You are right. In the app it is called like that. Now they corrected the Json. (Y)